# Apache web server Load balancing

Tags: apache, ssl, webserver, load-balancing, httpd.conf

We have a requirement in out environment where apache web server is installed, in which ssl and non-ssl port is configured to listen on 8080 and 4443 respectively. Now i want to load balance the request based on input, if the incoming request is ssl it should load balance the request to "https" and if its non-ssl it should load balance the request to "http". Have tried the below method but its not working as expected. Can someone help?

```
   <Proxy balancer://mybalancerhttp>
            BalancerMember http://localhost1/
            BalancerMember http://localhost2/
            ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / "balancer://mybalancerhttp/"
   ProxyPassReverse / "balancer://mybalancerhttp/"

   <Proxy balancer://mybalancerhttps>
            BalancerMember https://localhost1/
            BalancerMember https://localhost2/
            ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / "balancer://mybalancerhttps/"
   ProxyPassReverse / "balancer://mybalancerhttps/"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Those directives are fine, but you want to decide where to send based on client request.

The easiest method is to move each of those proxypass sets and their balancer definition to their own virtualhost.

This is

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName yourhostname.example.com
   <Proxy balancer://mybalancerhttp>
            BalancerMember http://localhost1/
            BalancerMember http://localhost2/
            ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / "balancer://mybalancerhttp/"
   ProxyPassReverse / "balancer://mybalancerhttp/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:4443>
ServerName yourhostname.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
....certs and all needed directives
<Proxy balancer://mybalancerhttps>
            BalancerMember https://localhost1/
            BalancerMember https://localhost2/
            ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / "balancer://mybalancerhttps/"
   ProxyPassReverse / "balancer://mybalancerhttps/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried in the same way. But its not working as expected. It returns the error page not found. Instead of load balancing if try to route the traffic to single host its working fine as below.                                                                                ProxyPass / https://hostname1/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://hostname1/

Comment: The configuration I told you will work, if you land in the correct virtualhost by using the correct names in servername plus the port. When you use ProxyPass / you are proxying everything so a 404 would come from the backend. Fix names and make sure you don't have anything else interfering or landed in another virtualhost. Hint "apachectl -S"

Comment: #here is the output .                    
#VirtualHost configuration:
#*:8080                 is a NameVirtualHost
#         default server test.one.com (/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf:484)
#         port 8080 namevhost test.one.com (/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf:484)
#         port 8080 namevhost login.test.one.com (/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf:510)
#*:4443                 is a NameVirtualHost
#         default server test.one.com (/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf:537)
#         port 4443 namevhost test.one.com (/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf:537)

Comment: #Main DocumentRoot: "/opt/apache/htdocs"
#Main ErrorLog: "/opt/apache/logs/error_log"
#Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
#Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
#Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
#Mutex proxy: using_defaults
#Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
#Mutex default: dir="/opt/apache/logs/" mechanism=default
#Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
#Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
#PidFile: "/opt/apache/logs/httpd.pid"
#Define: DUMP_VHOSTS

Comment: Sorry i was not allowed to add as a single comment hence separated. Not sure what is wrong in it

Comment: add the output in your question, in the comments section it is unreadable.

Comment: was not allowed, hence opened a separate thread and attached the output screen shot. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949372/apache-proxy-load-balancer-issue

Comment: I read it, ok the error you get is because all your virtualhosts are configured on port 4443 and not 443 and you are trying to access 443, and there is no config for that port, remove Listen directives with 443 if you just want 4443. Oh and for pasting stuff you can use a pastebin without ads like hastebin.com

Comment: I dont have any Listen directives with 443. Only 4443 was configured.

Comment: @user3171821 pay attention to everything you see and paste, your error says "[ssl:info] AH01998: Connection closed to child 1 with abortive shutdown (server test.server.com :443) "

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (/balancer-manager only worked on HTTP, not on HTTPS), and in my case the solution turned out to be to add this configuration in file "ssl.conf" instead of "httpd.conf".